# zsh case-insensitive mid-word completion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have the following in my `.zshrc` for case-insensitive tab completion. I encountered a situation where the tab completion fails, and I can't figure out why.

```
autoload -U compinit && compinit

zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{[:lower:][:upper:]}={[:upper:][:lower:]}' '+l:|=* r:|=*'
```

```
$ ls
Elephant/ ElephantExample/

$ cd ex[TAB]  # completion doesn't do anything here
$ cd x[TAB]   # completion works as expected --> ElephantExample/
$ cd E[TAB]   # completion works as expected --> Elephant
$ cd e[TAB]   # completion works as expected --> Elephant
```

Can someone help explain this to me? Is this a bug with zsh?

EDIT: I'm using "zsh 5.0.7 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0)"

Comment: try `zsh -f` then running run compinit, add the zstyle, then try.

Comment: @llua That will spawn a new subshell and not load any `.zshrc` correct? Just tried it and I get the same results.

Comment: it spawns a new zsh process, not a subshell.

Comment: Completing x[TAB] to ElephantExample/ is not what I would expect and not what happens in any of my experiments. If you want anything to match at the start of the line, you need something like zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'b:=* m:{[:lower:][:upper:]}={[:upper:][:lower:]}'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Changing the style to:

```
 zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{[:lower:][:upper:]}={[:upper:][:lower:]}' \
  '+l:|?=** r:|?=**'
```

Would allow `ex<tab>` to expand to `ElephantExample`, but there may be undesired side effects.

Comment: Thank you, could you point out what possible side effects might arise? The [docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Matching-Control) weren't too helpful for me. **EDIT:** I see... `x<tab>` now expands to `xElephant` rather than `ElephantExample`

Comment: The `_approximate` or `_correct` completers may be a better way of solving the problem, but anyway; it isn't a bug in zsh.

Comment: I found one undesirable side effect. Here is an example: `cd ~/hel<tab>` results in `cd ~~/` when there is no matching directory.